# Installing several *-dev packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm attempting to install several dev packages, but I keep into running into roadblocks, and this one is the most recent:

```
khishman@khishman-desktop:~/dev/powertab/build$ sudo aptitude install  qtbase5-dev  libboost-date-time-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-iostreams-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost-date-time-dev libboost-date-time1.58-dev{ab} libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-filesystem1.58-dev{ab} libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-iostreams1.58-dev{ab} libboost-system1.58-dev{ab} libqt5concurrent5{a} 
  libqt5opengl5-dev{ab} qt5-qmake{a} qtbase5-dev{b} qtbase5-dev-tools{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,362 kB of archives. After unpacking 23.3 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5opengl5-dev : Depends: libqt5opengl5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
 libboost-date-time1.58-dev : Depends: libboost-date-time1.58.0 (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 is installed.
 libboost-filesystem1.58-dev : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.58.0 (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 is installed.
 libboost-iostreams1.58-dev : Depends: libboost-iostreams1.58.0 (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 is installed.
 qtbase5-dev : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5dbus5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5gui5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5network5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5sql5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5test5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5widgets5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5xml5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
 libboost-system1.58-dev : Depends: libboost-system1.58.0 (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:              
1)      libboost-date-time-dev [Not Installed]                           
2)      libboost-date-time1.58-dev [Not Installed]                       
3)      libboost-filesystem-dev [Not Installed]                          
4)      libboost-filesystem1.58-dev [Not Installed]                      
5)      libboost-iostreams-dev [Not Installed]                           
6)      libboost-iostreams1.58-dev [Not Installed]                       
7)      libboost-system1.58-dev [Not Installed]                          
8)      libqt5opengl5-dev [Not Installed]                                
9)      qtbase5-dev [Not Installed]                                      

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                       
10)     qtbase5-dev recommends libqt5opengl5-dev (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7)


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
Abort.
```

It seems like the packages are not agreeing on the minor version, for example

`Depends: libqt5opengl5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed`

seems to be a conflict on between `16ubuntu7` and `16ubuntu7.2`
whereas

`Depends: libboost-iostreams1.58.0 (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 is installed.`

Seems to be a conflict between `5ubuntu3` and `5ubuntu3.1`

If you haven't noticed I'm using `aptitude` and not `apt-get`. The switch was an attempt to get past a similar hurdle (the "...but it is not going to be installed", "you have held broken packages" hurdle), I tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get install -f` just in case. I've also made sure to remove all the `unofficial` ppas

```
khishman@khishman-desktop:/etc/apt$ find ./ -name *.list -exec grep -E "^[\s]*deb" {} \;
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
```

But with no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [v5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libqt5opengl5-dev) in the `xenial-updates` repository but not in `xenial`.  enable that repo and run `sudo aptitude update` and retry your install command.  (should work with the `libboost` package as well.)

Comment: @quixotic the problem is I have a the 7.2 version and the dependencies were on a lower level version :/ I did add the us xenial-updates archive but I'm not sure if it made a difference, I might have simply not added right because it ended up fetching everything from the ca archives

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rejecting aptitude's first solution, and the second solution turned out to be downgrading most of the dependencies to an earlier version (from `16ubunt7.2` down to `16ubuntu7` and `5ubuntu3.1` down to `5ubuntu3`).  I'm not sure if this was the right thing to do, but I did achieve my goal.

```
khishman@khishman-desktop:/etc/apt$ sudo aptitude install  qtbase5-dev libboost-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-iostreams-dev
libboost-dev is already installed at the requested version (1.58.0.1ubuntu1)
libboost-dev is already installed at the requested version (1.58.0.1ubuntu1)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost-date-time-dev libboost-date-time1.58-dev{ab} libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-filesystem1.58-dev{ab} libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-iostreams1.58-dev{ab} libboost-regex1.58-dev{ab} libboost-serialization1.58-dev{ab} 
  libboost-serialization1.58.0{a} libboost-system1.58-dev{ab} libqt5concurrent5{a} libqt5opengl5-dev{ab} qt5-qmake{a} qtbase5-dev{b} qtbase5-dev-tools{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,944 kB of archives. After unpacking 29.4 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5opengl5-dev : Depends: libqt5opengl5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
 libboost-date-time1.58-dev : Depends: libboost1.58-dev (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 is installed.
 libboost-regex1.58-dev : Depends: libboost1.58-dev (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 is installed.
                          Depends: libboost-regex1.58.0 (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) but it is not going to be installed.
 libboost-serialization1.58-dev : Depends: libboost1.58-dev (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 is installed.
 libboost-filesystem1.58-dev : Depends: libboost1.58-dev (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 is installed.
 libboost-iostreams1.58-dev : Depends: libboost1.58-dev (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 is installed.
 qtbase5-dev : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5dbus5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5gui5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5network5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5sql5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5test5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5widgets5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
               Depends: libqt5xml5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is installed.
 libboost-system1.58-dev : Depends: libboost1.58-dev (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) but 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:              
1)      libboost-date-time-dev [Not Installed]                           
2)      libboost-date-time1.58-dev [Not Installed]                       
3)      libboost-filesystem-dev [Not Installed]                          
4)      libboost-filesystem1.58-dev [Not Installed]                      
5)      libboost-iostreams-dev [Not Installed]                           
6)      libboost-iostreams1.58-dev [Not Installed]                       
7)      libboost-regex1.58-dev [Not Installed]                           
8)      libboost-serialization1.58-dev [Not Installed]                   
9)      libboost-system1.58-dev [Not Installed]                          
10)     libqt5opengl5-dev [Not Installed]                                
11)     qtbase5-dev [Not Installed]                                      

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                       
12)     qtbase5-dev recommends libqt5opengl5-dev (= 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7)


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n   
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Install the following packages:                                                                 
1)      libboost-date-time1.58-dev [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]                                    
2)      libboost-filesystem1.58-dev [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]                                   
3)      libboost-iostreams1.58-dev [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]                                    
4)      libboost-regex1.58-dev [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]                                        
5)      libboost-regex1.58.0 [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]                                          
6)      libboost-serialization1.58-dev [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]                                
7)      libboost-serialization1.58.0 [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]                                  
8)      libboost-system1.58-dev [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]                                       

      Downgrade the following packages:                                                               
9)      libboost-date-time1.58.0 [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 (now) -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]      
10)     libboost-filesystem1.58.0 [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 (now) -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]     
11)     libboost-filesystem1.58.0:i386 [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 (now) -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]
12)     libboost-iostreams1.58.0 [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 (now) -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]      
13)     libboost-system1.58.0 [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 (now) -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]         
14)     libboost-system1.58.0:i386 [1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 (now) -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 (xenial)]    
15)     libqt5core5a [5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 (xenial)]                  
16)     libqt5dbus5 [5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 (xenial)]                   
17)     libqt5gui5 [5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 (xenial)]                    
18)     libqt5network5 [5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 (xenial)]                
19)     libqt5opengl5 [5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 (xenial)]                 
20)     libqt5printsupport5 [5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 (xenial)]           
21)     libqt5sql5 [5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 (xenial)]                    
22)     libqt5test5 [5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 (xenial)]                   
23)     libqt5widgets5 [5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 (xenial)]                
24)     libqt5xml5 [5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 (now) -> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 (xenial)]                    



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
```